# AWS SDK PHP2- Guzzle Service Builder

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, guzzle

I'm trying to get rid of my current authenticate model:

```
$s3_cfg = S3Client::factory(array(
    'key' => 'access',
    'secret' => 'secret'
             ));
```

and use  Guzzle Service model instead (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/guide/latest/service-s3.html#service-locator)

Here is what I have so far:

```
require '../s3up/vendor/autoload.php';
 use Aws\Common\Aws;
 $aws = Aws::factory('api.json');
 $client = $aws>get('apiauth');
```

and my api.json:

```
{
"includes": ["_aws"],
"services": {
  "apiauth": {
      "params": {
          "key": "access",
          "secret": "secret",
          "region": "us-west-2"
      }
  }
}
}
```

For any reason, I'm getting an error 500 and the following error message:

```
 Class '' not found in /s3up/vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Builder/ServiceBuilder.php on line 141
```

I installed AWS php SDK2 using composer. If I just remove the service locator and use basic auth instead, everything is OK, so I don't have any problem with my autoload.php

I get the JSON syntax from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awssdkdocsphp2/latest/gettingstartedguide/sdk-php2-using-the-sdk.html#sdk-php2-using-the-service-builder

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want these keys to be used for all of the services that the builder creates, then you should change "apiauth" to "default_settings". You would then call `$aws->get('s3')` to get an Amazon S3 client with the shared credentials.

Comment: Thanks Michael :)

BTW : If someone want to reuse my code, be sure to update:
 $client = $aws>get('s3');
with
 $client = $aws->get('s3');